# Sum with Stirling numbers

Tags: combinatorics, summation, stirling-numbers

Show that for each $n>1$

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}S(n,n-k) = (n-1)^n $$

where $S(n,m)$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: What have you tried?  I would start by substituting in the expression for the Stirling number as there are many identities involving binomial coefficients.  At least then others wouldn't have to look it up.

Comment: Of course that is the natural thing to do which I did but it does not seem going somewhere. Probably there are some tricks with the binomials which I don't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this:

$$ m^n = \sum_{j=1}^m  \binom{m}{j} \,   j! \, S(n,j)  $$

The left side is the number of ways of placing $n$ distinct balls in $m$ distinct cells. The right side is the same, each term corresponds to the number of configurations that have $j$ occupied (non-empty) cells.

Then, replacing $k=m-j+1$:

$$ m^n =  \sum_{j=1}^m  \frac{m!}{(m-j)!} \, S(n,j) =  \sum_{k=1}^m  \frac{m!}{(k-1)!} \, S(n,m-k+1)$$

Pick the special case  $m=n-1$, and you get your identity.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are trying to show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!} {n\brace n-k}
= (n-1)^n.$$

Recall the species for set partitions which is
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U} \mathfrak{P}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$
which gives the generating function
$$G(z, u) = \exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

This implies for the sum being evaluated that it is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!} 
\times n! [z^n] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}.$$

This is
$$n! [z^n] \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k-1} (\exp(z)-1)^{n-k}
\\ = n! [z^n] (\exp(z)-1)^{n-1}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k-1} (\exp(z)-1)^{-(k-1)}
\\ =  n! [z^n] (\exp(z)-1)^{n-1} \times
\left(-(\exp(z)-1)^{-(n-1)}
+ \sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1} (\exp(z)-1)^{-(k-1)} \right)
\\ =  n! [z^n] (\exp(z)-1)^{n-1} \times
\\ \left(-(\exp(z)-1)^{-(n-1)}
+ \left(1 + \frac{1}{\exp(z)-1}\right)^{n-1}\right)
\\ =  n! [z^n] (\exp(z)-1)^{n-1} \times
\\ \left(-(\exp(z)-1)^{-(n-1)}
+ \left(\frac{\exp(z)}{\exp(z)-1}\right)^{n-1}\right)
\\ = n! [z^n] (-1 + \exp(z(n-1)))
= (n-1)^n.$$

**Addendum.**
I just realized that starting from 
$$n! [z^n] \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k-1} (\exp(z)-1)^{n-k}$$
we can also continue with
$$n! [z^n] \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k-1} (\exp(z)-1)^{(n-1)-(k-1)}
\\ = n! [z^n]
\left(-1 + 
\sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1} (\exp(z)-1)^{(n-1)-(k-1)}\right)
\\ = n! [z^n]
\left(-1 + (\exp(z)-1+1)^{n-1}\right)
\\= n! [z^n] \left(-1 + \exp(z(n-1))\right)
= (n-1)^n.$$